# Sales_flat_order missing data magento

Tags: magento

my sales_flat_order_table is recording customer_firstname and customer_lastname from amazon and ebay orders but for magento site orders its leaving these fields blank. Though i can see the names in admin order details.

Answer (score 0):

I need it for a custom grid, found names in sales_flat_order_address so joined the two to get names that were missing in sales_flat_order table.